# Extending a vendor file in laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to extend a class TBMsg from a vendor Tzookb/TBMSg into class Messaging in a new file UserMessaging that I created in library. Below is my code in UserMessaging file.

```
 namespace Messaging;
 class Messaging extends \Tzookb\TBMsg { 
 public function getConversationMessages($conv_id, $user_id) { }
```

I have added allias like below in my app.php

```
'Messaging'       => 'Messaging\UserMessaging',
```

My controller code to call the class is as below

```
Messaging::getConversationMessages($conv_id, $user_id);
```

I am getting an error "Class 'Tzookb\TBMsg' not found"

Comment: shouldn't the alias be `'Messaging' => 'Messaging\Messaging'`?

Comment: @zwaqcky still getting the same error after changing the alias, sorry.

Comment: it's just an additional error, when you'd be using the alias. not the main one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class you want to extend from is actually **Tzookb/TBMsg/TBMsg**. so your messaging class should read:

`class Messaging extends \Tzookb\TBMsg\TBMsg { ...`

reference: [TBMsg.php](https://github.com/tzookb/tbmsg/blob/master/src/Tzookb/TBMsg/TBMsg.php)

Comment: that worked ike a charm, thanks, I am getting a new error "Non-static method Messaging\Messaging::getConversationMessages() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"

Comment: for the `Messaging` to be used as an alias, you'd need a facade.